# SAPUI5 bind array row index to array row data in xml view

Tags: xml, view, binding, sapui5

I have two array :

one containing my data : the array name is arrayData

one containing the index of my data arrayIndex

In my xml view I loop over my arrayIndex and I want to display the row corresponding in arrayData.

Is it possible? if yes how too?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slick way to do it: send the job to your Formatter.js function.

1. I'll bind an aggregation, and let's say I expand to some AddressSet:

   ```
   <Table id="someTable" 
       items="{path: '/MainSet',
       parameters : 
           {expand:'AddressSet'}
       }"
       growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true"
    >
   ```
2. Then create a control within the aggregation where I send an expanded entityset to my formatter

   ```
   <Text 
      text="{
         parts:[
           {path: 'AddressSet'},
         ],
         formatter: '.formatter.addressInSearchCatalog'
       }"
   ```

   >
3. Then, in the Formatter, you'll notice that the expanded entityset simply returns you a string that is the relative path of the object. Using this path, I can access the property from my oData model! Obviously, in Javascript I can simply grab the first (or second, or fifth, or last) array item from the array I pass into the formatter function.

   ```
    addressInSearchCatalog: function(otherSet){
               var oModel = this._oCatalog.getModel();
               var addressObj = oModel.getObject("/" + otherSet[0]);//use absolute binding
                   return(addressObj.HouseNumber + space + addressObj.Street + space + addressObj.City + ", " + addressObj.State + space + addressObj.Zip);
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge `arrayData` into your `arrayIndex` first, so your structure may look like this:

```
{ arrayIndex: [
    { text: 'test1', arrayData: { otherText: 'testData2' } },
    { text: 'test2', arrayData: { otherText: 'testData2' } }
]}
```

Now you may use a Table within a Table (`sap.m` Namespace). Be sure, to define your models and modelnames before.

```
<Table items="{arrayIndex>/}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Headline"/>
        </Column>   
    </colums>           
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{arrayIndex>text}"/>
                        <Table items="{path: 'arrayIndex>arrayData', templateShareable:false}">
                            <columns class="backgroundBlue">
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="Headline arrayData"/>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                                <items>
                                    <ColumnListItem>
                                        <cells>
                                            <Text text="{arrayIndex>otherText}"/>
                                        </cells>
                                    </ColumnListItem>
                                </items>
                        </Table>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
</Table>
```

You must use `{path: '...', templateShareable:false}` for your second table in order to work properly.